# In Visual Studio Code, can I start a debugging session with custom arguments without editing settings.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm building a program that acts on files that it has to download from one of my company's servers. We have several million of these. For instance, my normal invocation could be:

```
python my_script.py file-id
```

And then my_script.py will go download file-id and do its work on it.

It's useful to be able to specify one fixed file to download and act on while I make changes to our code, but when it comes to testing at scale, I'll usually find out that maybe a dozen files couldn't be processed correctly, and I need to go and debug our program with it.

For this purpose, editing the `settings.json` file works, but it's kind of cumbersome that I have to change the parameter, save, run, and revert every time I just want to test a new input.

Is there a way that I pass an argument to a debug configuration as I start debugging, instead of having to change the settings.json file?